# setcookie doesnt work

Tags: php, setcookie

After I set this cookie it doesn't work. When I leave the domain part away and test it on the localhost, I can echo the cookie though:

```
setcookie("email",$email,0, "/", ".domainname.com");
```

Comment: are you requesting localhost via `something.domainname.com` (eg, via a host mapping to 127.0.0.1 or just via localhost ?

Comment: forget localhost, it needs to work on domainname.com (not my real domein ofcourse)

Comment: you cannot test on the local server for another domainname, unless you host-map it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test on `localhost`, than make the domain `localhost`.

You wouldn't expect setting it to `google.com` to allow you to set cookies for `google.com` would you?

Comment: You've read over the part:\
When I leave the domain part away and test it on the localhost I can echo the cookie tho

Comment: I need to work it on the domain, not the localhost. On the localhost it works perfectly when I omit the domein paramter in setcookie. When I omit it when using the script online on the domein then it doesnt work apparently.

Comment: @Jay does the domain you set match the one your site is using?

Comment: Yes. I can't type the real name here tho. So it's domainname.com and the parameter in setcookie is therefore ".domainname.com"

Comment: @Jay OK and I guess you have confirmed `$email` contains what you want it to, the cookie isn't being overwritten and you are checking this whilst in the same session? BTW, have you examined the headers to see if the cookie header is being set?

Comment: When I put $email into a session variable to stay logged in for the session being it remembers that value so $email is okay. Also I dont overwrite the cookie after setting it unless I log out.
This might sound stupid, but how do I set the cookie header? (is that server sided?)

Comment: @Jay The cookie header is what `setcookie()` sets up. Basically it sends the cookie data you set with every request so your browser knows what to do with it. What browser do you use? Google for your browser name and *HTTP header sniffing* or similar.

Comment: I have cookies on in all my browsers (FF, IE, Chrome, Safari) and they seem to work for every website except for mine. Also other users of my website have this same problem.

Comment: @Jay Yeah, but still, looking at the actual header can be useful. Perhaps the header is malformed.

Comment: I've installed Live HTTP Header, but what should I see out of it?

Comment: @Jay Headers that set the cookie.

Comment: I get this:
Cookie: __utma=129491722.686443174.1282223499.1304166493.1304232048.138; __utmz=129491722.1304166493.137.15.utmcsr=sn116w.snt116.mail.live.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/mail/InboxLight.aspx; __utmb=129491722.15.10.1304232048; __utmc=129491722; PHPSESSID=c12fe60b4b0ced223712ebc61565116b

Comment: @Jay Just looks like Google Analytics and the PHP session identifier. No `email` cookie.

Comment: When I run the website on my localhost I see the set-cookie header, but when I run the website online I don't see it.

Comment: I've mailed the provider and they said they support cookies. So there must be something wrong with my code..